# Server-Side rendering "React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid."

Tags: reactjs, redux, single-page-application

On my react-redux-aspnetcore spa I have server side rendering enabled. However, I am using good old cookie based authentication. So I don't have server-side access to the API where authentication is necessary.

Here is my action creator:

```
export const actionCreators: AC = {
    requestEntries: (weekStartDate: string): ActionCreator => (dispatch, getState) => {
        // Only load data if it's something we don't already have (and are not already loading)
        if (getState().activeUserEntries.date != weekStartDate && getState().activeUserEntries.isLoading == false) {
            console.log('aa');

            let fetchTask = fetch(`/api/entries?date=${weekStartDate}`, {
                credentials: 'same-origin'
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((data: EntrySet) => {
                    dispatch(new ReceiveEntries(weekStartDate, data));
                }).catch((a)=>{
                    dispatch(new InitEntriesState());
                });

            addTask(fetchTask); // Ensure server-side prerendering waits for this to complete
            dispatch(new RequestEntries(weekStartDate));
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see the `fetch` method has `.catch((a)=>{dispatch(new InitEntriesState());});` part. Which catches errors on server side because authentication is failed and `response.json()` throws an exception since the view result is not a json string.

So if authentication fails, I dispatch `InitEntriesState()` which makes my reducer return the initial state for the part of the store.

In the end, I get the diabolic warning message:

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. 
This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated 
on the server was not what the client was expecting. 
React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the 
benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated 
is different on the client or server:
    (client) v data-reactid="68">...Loading</div></di
    (server) v data-reactid="68"><table class="table
```

So how can I fix this? Or should I change my approach to the problem? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the question right it sounds like the server renders a page that is not authenticated, and then when the client loads it renders the authenticated page. Is that correct? You can test this by disabling js in your browser and seeing what the server renders on its own.

That cryptic error message just means that the server and client didn't render identical HTML, which means that most of the performance benefits of server side rendering was lost. If you truly can't get server side rendering to work and the majority of your app looks completely different on the server render vs the client render, it probably makes sense to just have the server return a loading state and not even try to render a react application. That warning will only show up in developer mode to warn you, it won't show up in production.

Comment: That's right. Do you think it is wrong to use cookie based authentication state management on single page applications? Because almost any page in my application has components that needs data from the authentication required API of mine.

Comment: This would spill into another question, but the client request passes the cookies you need to your server, so you should be able to get something working where your server request is also successful. Again, that would be a separate issue, and if you're unable to do that for some reason it might just be fine to return a spinner from the server and auth in the client. I don't know your business use case or why you're doing server rendering necessarily.